# Changed behavior how to cast and getstring enums with vs2012 in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio-2012, enums, c++-cli, visual-studio-2005

As the support of C++/CLI was really bad in 2010 (no wizard for c++/cli!), one of my project is still VS2005 C++/CLI. Now is the time to migrate this last project. Unfortunately it comes with errors during compile time. Two of them I do not understand, because they worked perfectly before, try to compile this small snippet on VS2012:

```
        enum class EMyEnum
        {
            Unknown,
            NotBetter,
        };

        Array ^lEnums=Enum::GetValues(EMyEnum::typeid);
        Object ^test=lEnums->GetValue(0);
        EMyEnum t=(EMyEnum)test;  // VS2012 ERROR -> Cannot cast
        String ^thetext=t.ToString(); // VS2012 ERROR -> Left of ToString() needs object
```

Needless to say that in VS2005 it not only compile without error or warning, it also works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a problem in VS2012 and up.  This is caused by the C++11 language standard adopting the `enum class` syntax.  The C++/CLI compiler can now no longer distinguish a managed enum type from an unmanaged one.  The cast from Object^ is only valid for a managed enum.

The workaround is silly but effective, you should explicitly specify the accessibility of the *enum class*.  Something that's not legal in C++11 but valid in C++/CLI.  Fix:

```
    private enum class EMyEnum      // Note: added private
    {
        Unknown,
        NotBetter,
    };
```

Or use *public*.

Comment: You know you are awesome? :-)